# Subset ('get') ee.List using multiple indices in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I need to split a long, flattened list of coordinates by even indices (longitude) and odd indices (latitude). Here's an example list:

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[24.331249999999955, 1.0646598040515236],
      [24.331249999999955, -13.828337374026978],
      [44.018749999999955, -13.828337374026978],
      [44.018749999999955, 1.0646598040515236]]], null, false);
var flatList = roi.coordinates().flatten()
```

In Python it works great using `flatList[::2]` for even indices and `flatList[1::2]` for odd indices. In normal Google Earth Engine I'm trying the following to first create lists of indices:

```
// Even indices
var even = ee.List.sequence(0, flatList.size().subtract(1), 2)
// Odd indices
var odd = ee.List.sequence(1, flatList.size().subtract(1), 2)
```

No problems there, but it then seems bizarrely difficult to subset my list using my  lists of indices. I'm trying this:

```
// Even indices (longitude)
var lons = even.map(function(i){return(flatList.get(i))});
// Odd indices (latitude)
var lats = odd.map(function(i){return(flatList.get(i))});
```

For long lists of coordinates (i.e. large FeatureCollections) this is *very* slow. I'm assuming it's because of the call to `map`? But I don't see any alternatives in the documentation.

For background, the reason I am doing this is to create a minimum bounding box from potentially complex FeatureCollections. The FeatureCollections are species range maps, which may contain many geometries of different types and thus requires me to completely flatten the coordinates to be able to extract the minimum and maximum latitudes and longitudes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ee.List.splice` to do the subsetting:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-list-splice